# How to join two files based on fields with out rearrange the colums order?

Tags: text-processing, join

I want to create a file that contains columns from two input files. File1 is like:

```
s,a
k,b
h,c
```

File2 is:

```
f,a
g,b
```

The output should be like:

```
s,a,f
k,b,g
h,c,-
```

am using the join command like

```
join  -a1 -a2 -t , -1 2 -2 2 -o auto -e "-" file1 file2 > joinoutput
```

am getting  out put like

```
a,s,f
b,k,g
c,h,-
```

please help me to fix ,
I cant able to specify the order of column like -o '1.1' like. if in my first file number of column is n and second file it is n i need to see n+n -1 
thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot give an answer for n>2 because you have not specified the output order of the fields on each line when n>2.  You can even specify with the `-o` syntax, for example for n=3, would it be, "1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.3"  or "1.1 1.3 1.2 2.1 2.3" or something else?  I think we may have to build the output format string after looking at the files.

Comment: Does it have to be shell? This is pretty easy in Perl.

Comment: @Sobrique i dont know perl help me pls

Answer (score 0):

Replace `-o auto` with `-o '1.1 1.2 2.1'`

to get:

```
s,a,f
k,b,g
h,c,-
```

Comment: I cant able to specify the order of column like this. if in my first file number of column is n and second file it is n  i need to see n+n -1  columns ,using -o '1.1 1.2 2.1'  i only get 3 columns as output

Answer (score 0):

In `perl` something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Data Dumper is for diagnostic printing
use Data::Dumper;


#open second file for reading
open( my $file2, '<', 'sampleb.txt' ) or die $!;

#slurp this file into a hash (key value map) - reverse them, so we use
#the second value as a lookup key. 
my %key_values = reverse map {/(\w+),(\w+)/} <$file2>;
close($file2);

#print what we got in that map for diag reasons. 
print Dumper \%key_values;

 #open the first file
open( my $file1, '<', 'samplea.txt' ) or die $!;
#iterate by line
while (<$file1>) {
    chomp; #strip trailing line feed. 
    #split this line on comma
    my ( $key, $value ) = split /,/;
    #loopup "$value" in that hash we created - use that if it's defined, or '-' otherwise. 
    print join( ",", $key, $value, $key_values{$value} // '-' ), "\n";
}
close ( $file1 );
```

Outputs:

```
s,a,f
k,b,g
h,c,-
```

Comment: i need to pass the lookup value index directly from both files based on that i need to join as   join  -t ,  -1 2 -2 2